# Match every other character in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
k1|v1|k2|v2|k3|v3|k4|v4
```

and I want to match on every other `|` so I can change the string to

```
k1:v1|k2:v2|k3:v3|k4:v4
```

I know I can match on `|` by doing a grouping like `(|)` but I can't figure out how to match only every other pipe.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use the 'k' and 'v' alternation.

Comment: You haven't shown [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). You haven't tagged your question with what programming language you're using to know what flavor of regex is to be used. Voting to close this as too broad.

Comment: @RDay.  Do you really want me to write the 10,000 things I've tried?  I'm assuming its a pretty basic regex question and would take an expert all 5 seconds to answer.  Stop trolling stack questions looking for opportunities to write "What have your tried?".

Comment: @GoBrewers14 It may be annoying, but it prevents users more or less from asking "do my work/homework"-questions.

Comment: I am with @GoBrewers14 on this one. It is a simple question, and other than the tagging, it really adds nothing to ask him to show what has been tried so far. This is not a problem in any specific code - nor too elaborate to answer quickly, it is just a general question deserving a general answer.

Comment: @palsch What evidence is there that this is homework?  I'm at work, regex isn't my forte, I didn't want to spend 5 hours figuring this out.

Comment: No, I don't mean this is homework. I don't really understand the downvotes, too. I just wanted to defend the "What have you tried?"-question. To see that this is no homework I just must have a look at your reputation score. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Match with:

```
([^|]*)\|([^|]*(\||$))
```

Replace with `$1:$2`.

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/yV0aV6/1)

---

General idea:

- `[^|]*` - multiple non-`|` characters
- `()` defines a group
- `(\||$)` - a `|` or the end of the string
- The entire regex reads as *multiple non `|` characters in the first group, followed by a `|`, followed by multiple non `|` characters and a `|` or end of string in the second group*

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help.